# Do not show on default page

Tags: php

I have a header which is showed on all my pages. In that header I have a banner.

Is there a way to not show that banner on the root page as well as other pages?

Something like this:

```
If (!Root OR !/test.php) {
    BANNER
}
```

Comment: look in $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] to see what page you are on, probably worth running print_r($_SERVER) as what is set depends of a few things

Comment: it depends on how your site structur is. do you have one index.php for all pages? do you use a template system? give us more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function pageName() {
 return substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],"/")+1);
}

if (pageName() != 'index.php' && pageName() != 'test.php') {
  BANER
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to test the value of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, which gives you the URI.

Something like that:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '/test.php') {
  //Display your banner
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   <?php
       $url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
       if ($url !== '/') && ($url  !== '/test.php') {
          banner();
       }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about the magic constant [`__FILE__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) to determine which PHP-Script is currently running?

But you could also use the [`$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)-variable to just get the Scripts name (without the full path).